# Starting with encog framework workbench

Tags: executable-jar, encog

I am new to neural network and I am having problem with starting Encog workbench.
I  have read the quick start guide but it could not help me.I am trying to use Encog work-bench and every time I try to run the executable jar file I am getting **the problem no manifest attribute, in graddle-wrapper.jar.** Can anybody please help me out with this ?And do we need to learn **Maven** or **Gradle** for Encog or simply basic java is enough?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DpaW.jpg)

Comment: You need to show what you tried and what happened, so that there's a specific problem we can respond to.

Comment: I tried to open the executable jar file,the gradle-wrapper and I am getting no manifest attribute,in graddle-wrapper.jar

Comment: Edit your question to provide the important details.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I run the jar file. I imported the maven project into eclipse. After fixed a few compiler problems, I run it after one more fail since there is no configure file in the installation. After that, you can run it.

Comment: tq........I just installed both maven and gradle in Netbeans and it worked